# replace nan with random value between the existing max and min values in its column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have missing data and would like to replace the NaN's with random values from between the existing min and max for that column (different filled values for each NaN). I have been trying things like **the below** but it doesn't work and I am not sure how to loop through the columns correctly as the min max will change for each column.

```py
import datetime 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def fill_blanks(df):
  
    for i in list(df):
        for x in i:
            if type(x) is datetime.datetime:
                return x
                continue
            if pd.isnull(x):
                #print (i,x)
                x=(np.random.uniform(df[i].min(), df[i].max()))   
                return x
            else:
                return x

df.applymap(fill_blanks)
```

example data

```
d = {'Date': ['2015-09-01 09:00:00', '2015-09-02 09:00:00','2015-09-03 09:00:00','2015-09-01 09:00:00',], 'col2': [np.nan, 102,np.nan,105],'col3': [1, np.nan,3,2.5,],'col4': [0.0001, 0.0002,np.nan,0.0003]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

gives

```
Out[5]:
                  Date   col2  col3    col4
0  2015-09-01 09:00:00    NaN   1.0  0.0001
1  2015-09-02 09:00:00  102.0   NaN  0.0002
2  2015-09-03 09:00:00    NaN   3.0     NaN
3  2015-09-01 09:00:00  105.0   2.5  0.0003
```

desired output might be:

```
Out[5]:
                  Date   col2  col3    col4
0  2015-09-01 09:00:00  102.5   1.0  0.0001
1  2015-09-02 09:00:00  102.0   2.0  0.0002
2  2015-09-03 09:00:00  104.5   3.0  0.0002
3  2015-09-01 09:00:00  105.0   2.5  0.0003
```

Comment: If you have multiple nans in a single column, should the filled value be the same or different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
numeric_cols = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns

df[numeric_cols] = df[numeric_cols].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(np.random.uniform(x.min(), x.max(), 1)[0]))
```

Output:

```
                  Date       col2      col3      col4
0  2015-09-01 09:00:00  100.00000  1.000000  0.000100
1  2015-09-02 09:00:00  102.00000  1.435334  0.000200
2  2015-09-03 09:00:00  103.97625  3.000000  0.962672
3  2015-09-01 09:00:00  105.00000  2.500000  0.000300
```

If you want every nan in column to be filled with different random value, use:

```
df[numeric_cols] = df[numeric_cols].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(pd.Series(np.random.uniform(x.min(), x.max(), len(x)))))
```